# Multiple user stream to one StockTwits widget

Tags: widget, stocktwits

Is it possible to aggregate multiple user stream into a StockTwits widget or is it limited to one ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just limited to one username or symbol. Here's the [widget documentation](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/widget).

Comment: Hi @Sayem Khan [this](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/widget)  seems to be moved do you know where I can access it